# Code blocks work separately but not together

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a function for my chrome extension. It's supposed to move all tabGroups to the left most position in alphabetical order and then sort the rest of the tabs in alphabetical order aswell.
The problem is when I remove this code block everything works fine, meaning the tabGroups gets moved to the left most position. But when I add it back it stops working. The thing is that the code block works on it's own if I manually move the tabGroups myself. Any help is appreciated!

```js
for (let i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < titles.length; j++) {
          if (tabs[i + moveIndex].title == titles[j]) {
            chrome.tabs.move(tabs[i + moveIndex].id, { index: (j + moveIndex) });
          }
        }
      }
```

This is the full function, with tabs being: `let tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true });`

```js
async function titleSort(tabs) {
  // Puts groups in current window into an array
  let groups = await chrome.tabGroups.query({ windowId: -1 });
  console.log(groups);

  // Separates titles into a different array
  let groupTitles = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    groupTitles.push(groups[i].title);
  }
  // Sorts the array alphabetically
  groupTitles.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
  console.log(groupTitles);

  // Put groups into an array in alphabetical order
  let groupsAlph = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < groupTitles.length; j++) {
      if (groupTitles[i] == groups[j].title) {
        groupsAlph.push(groups[j]);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(groupsAlph);

  chrome.storage.sync.get(["preserveGroupOrder"], (data) => {
    if (data.preserveGroupOrder == false) {
      // Separates titles into a different array
      let titles = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        titles.push(tabs[i].title);
      }

      // Sorts the array alphabetically
      titles.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));

      // Checks if the titles match and rearranges the tabs accordingly
      for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < titles.length; j++) {
          if (tabs[i].title == titles[j]) {
            chrome.tabs.move(tabs[i].id, { index: j });
          }
        }
      }
    } else if (data.preserveGroupOrder == true) {
      let tabsInGroup = [];
      // Resets values to 0 in tabsInGroup
      for (let i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
        tabsInGroup[i] = 0;
      }

      // Gets the amount of tabs in each group
      for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < groups.length; j++) {
          if (tabs[i].groupId == groupsAlph[j].id) {
            tabsInGroup[j]++;
          }
        }
      }
      console.log(tabsInGroup);
      
      // Moves groups to the left most positions
      let moveIndex = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < groupsAlph.length; i++) {
        chrome.tabGroups.move(groupsAlph[i].id, { index: moveIndex });
        moveIndex += tabsInGroup[i];
      }
      console.log(moveIndex);

      // Separates titles into a different array
      let titles = [];
      let tabsLength = tabs.length - moveIndex;
      for (let i = 0; i < tabsLength; i++) {
        titles.push(tabs[i + moveIndex].title);
      }

      // Sorts the array alphabetically
      titles.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
      console.log(titles);
      
      // TODO: Sort the rest of the tabs (works separately)
      // Checks if the titles match and rearranges the tabs accordingly
      for (let i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < titles.length; j++) {
          if (tabs[i + moveIndex].title == titles[j]) {
            chrome.tabs.move(tabs[i + moveIndex].id, { index: (j + moveIndex) });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly confident that the issue is that you're not requerying tabs after you move tab groups:

```js
chrome.tabGroups.move(groupsAlph[i].id, { index: moveIndex });
```

If you're only creating the tabs index once, then if tabs 6 - 8 are part of a group, and the group gets moved to index spots 0-2 by that line, your tabs variable does not know that unless you requery. So when you start resorting tabs 3 through 8, you're including tabs you don't want to and excluding tabs that you do. If for some reason you don't want to requery, you could keep track of the index numbers where you find tabs and have your title builder start at zero and skip the tabs. I.e., instead of ->

```js
for (let i = 0; i < tabsLength; i++) {
  titles.push(tabs[i + moveIndex].title); ...
```

Something like ->

```js
for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
  if (isNotGroupMember[i]) {
    titles.push(tabs[i].title); ...
```

You would need to readjust some other pieces, but there's a good chance that will be the case regardless.

If that's not the issue, it's not clear from your code and I have a second hypothesis, but I'd try that first.

Also, it's not your question, but you may be interested in sorting arrays of objects by a key, rather than separating out the titles, sorting those, and then match sorting them back into place. See an example at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_array_sort_object1). Although maybe there's a good reason to build your own sort.

Comment: Thank you so much! The requerying was the issue. I'll take a look into objects aswell.